# SEO HTML status 301 on files?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, redirect

Good morning.

Currently trudging through SEO part of a website and i'm using a checklist found on http://www.clickminded.com/seo-checklist/ found parts of to be very helpful.

I have gotten to a part which suggested using Scream Frog SEO which has flagged up quite a significant amount of 301 redirects on images/css/js and even links to other parts of my website.

example of this would be :

Address : http://c-elec.co.uk/welcome/gourmet

Content : text/html

Status code  : 301

Status : Permanently moved

Every 301 has the same error and content type even if its an image,js file or css always having their redirect URI has the same as their original address.

I am not sure if this is a problem with how my project is structure or a server issue but other sites i've checked on the server have no 301 when scanned. I'm using php/codeigniter with foundation 5 on a NGINX server.

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that some of your resources are included using http://www.example.tld.
These requests are redirected to http://example.tld automatically, maybe by some rewrite rule or whatever.

So this request: http://www.c-elec.co.uk/js/app.js is redirected to http://c-elec.co.uk/js/app.js

You need to find out where this redirect is done or include your resources with http://example.tld.

BTW: You are including JS code after the closing HEAD and after the closing BODY tag.

Comment: ah right thanks, i didn't set up the server config files that was the server admin so maybe he's got the redirects set up to do this. Will this cause any SEO issues?

Comment: As in the JS code could you please advise proper locations for it , i have it after the head closes before the Nav tags in the header file and yup your right just saw some JS in the footer after the closing body tag

Comment: It should be before the closing tags, not after.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting my answer.